# registeredFields vs fields

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

[image]

Using redux-form, I created a Wizard where the form is split on multiple components that share the same form name.

When I look into my DevTools, I notice there is only the field of the first page that is "registered".

What is the difference between `registeredFields` and `fields` in this context?

Answer (score 1):

`fields` holds all the meta state information about each of your fields. e.g. `touched`, `active`, etc.

`registeredFields` is the list of all the fields (`name` and `type`) that are currently on the page. This is used to only run validation on fields that are on the page.